# Keyword var required in front of struct value type when used as a parameter in a function

Tags: ios, swift, struct, var

Why is the keyword var required in front of a struct's value type parameter when used in a function?

```
struct MyValueType {
    var name:String
    var assignment:String
    var grade:Int
}

class MyReferenceType{
    var name:String
    var assignment:String
    var grade:Int
    init(name:String,assignment:String,grade:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.assignment = assignment
        self.grade = grade
    }
}

var myRef = MyReferenceType(name:"Jon",assignment:"Math Test 1",grade:90)

print(myRef.assignment)
func extraCreditReferenceType(ref:MyReferenceType,extraCredit:Int){
    ref.grade += extraCredit
}

func extraCreditValueType(var val:MyValueType,extraCredit:Int){
    val.grade += extraCredit
}

var ref = MyReferenceType(name:"Jon",assignment:"Math Test 1",grade:90)

print(ref.grade)
extraCreditReferenceType(ref,extraCredit:5)
print("Reference: \(ref.name) - \(ref.grade)")



var val = MyValueType(name:"Jon",assignment:"Math Test 1",grade:90)
extraCreditValueType(val,extraCredit:5)
print("Value: \(val.name) - \(val.grade)")
```

The line in question is the following function:

```
func extraCreditValueType(var val:MyValueType,extraCredit:Int){
    val.grade += extraCredit
}
```

By removing the keyword var, the code won't compile.

Comment: Your func extraCreditValueType is likely not doing what you think it does. It's not going to modify val in the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because structs as parameters are `let` types by default, and because you are making changes to the struct in the function, it would have to be a `var`

It seems the `var` in the parameter is not going to be allowed in swift 3.0, so will have to remove it anyway eventually

Also your `extraCreditValueType` func is not going to do what you think it does, since structs are pass by value, the parameter `val` is not the same as the `val` on the outside of the function, therefore making changes to it in the function will not have an effect outside the function. you should either make `MyValueType` a class (and prob change the name) or return the `val` from the function to be used outside of the function

Comment: ... or make it an `inout` parameter.

Comment: ah ye, forgot about that

Comment: In Swift 3.0, "var" in front of a parameter isn't just "not required", it is not allowed. Parameters are _always_ constants. If you like, you can in your first line of the function write "var param = param" which creates a variable with the same name and value as the parameter.